# How to define the order (orderBy) within the model itself in laravel?

Tags: laravel

How can I define the order (orderBy) of the table in the model itself so that when I call:

```
$users = \App\Users::all();
```

and get all users by the pre defined orderBy default, without the need to:

```
$users = \App\Users::orderByDesc('id');
```

Is there a way to define such a default prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default prop, but you can write your own method:

```
public function ordered()
{
    return $this->orderByDesc('id')->get();
}
```

And then use it:

```
$users = \App\Users::ordered();
```

Comment: That's it. Thx.